# unsafe value used in a resource URL context : Angular DomSanitizer

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to embed a dynamic google map url in my component which has an iFrame in it but I am getting the error `unsafe value used in a resource URL context`. Here is what I have tried using `DomSanitizer` but the issue still exists

```
<iframe src="{{mapURL}}" width="100%" height="250" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy">
</iframe>
```

In my component.ts

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, } from '@angular/platform-browser';

mapURL: SafeResourceUrl

constructor( public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

var url = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q="
      + this.tenant.latitude
      + ","
      + this.tenant.longitude
      + "&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed";
this.mapURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change your html like this.

```
<iframe [src]="mapURL" width="100%" height="250" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy">
</iframe>
```

it's work for me,please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g4q9d8?file=src/app/app.component.html